# Where to send off-topic well researched questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have stumbled upon a quandry... Where should a question such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213070/true-random-number-generator-c?noredirect=1#comment50427714_31213070 be directed?

It appears there are four possible destinations for this question:

1. Stack Overflow
2. Code Review SE
3. Computer Science SE
4. Programmers SE

However it does not appear to fit in any one of these options for the reasons outlined below:

First, the question is off-topic on stack overflow; due to the code presented running as expected and functioning properly.

The most likely option to me seems to be codereview.stackexchange.com as the user is asking if a piece of code is properly designed. However it is out of the scope of codereview which works only with "good" practice and not if the code functions correctly.

The next I considered was the Computer Science forum. However Computer Science tends to have a more theoretical and mathematical approach, rather than examining a specific piece of code for correctness.

Finally Programmers forum is inapplicable as they deal only in programming concepts, and not actual specific problems relating to a single piece of code.

So I beseech you, fellow Stack Overflow-ers, where should a question such as this be directed?

So far I have been unable to find any established precedent regarding a universally off-topic, well researched, question. 
Some stuff I looked at in an attempt to discern an answer is below:

[Are Computer Science questions really off-topic on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254756/are-computer-science-questions-really-off-topic-on-stack-overflow)

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Thank you greatly for your consideration and input.

Comment: If they're off-topic then, well researched or not, **they're off-topic**. The SE network is not, and has never tried to be, the right home for **all** questions.

Comment: that's "well researched?" it looks like a homework... teacher gives code, asks "is it truly random?" and "if not, prove your answer".... honestly, I don't see why this is "well researched"... (note, not saying the question isn't interesting here :P)

Comment: @Patrice I suppose it could be viewed that way, I just prefer to give the benefit of doubt that it isn't a homework question. (And if so, it is an interesting idea that most likely has a some time and thought put into it.) I suppose in a way I am just over-zealous in attempting to assist people and give back to the SO community. (Which I have gone to for assistance with problems for years.) I've also never taken a CS class, so I guess I figured a homework problem would be... well... more boring and not as interesting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess I just really want to help people out and hate seeing unanswered questions. Do you know any out-of-network sites that would be appropriate for these kinds of questions?

Comment: @Rootix this isn't a clearinghouse for the rest of the internet, either!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree; but if someone is asking for help, should we not do our best to assist them? (Or in this case direct them to where others are best suited to assist them.)

Comment: @Rootix fair enough. But I still fail to see how that question is "well-researched"... there doesn't seem to be any tries by the OP to find anything. He just posts code, asking for the randomness of it. To me, what makes it REEKS of a homework is the way the second question is asked... "if not, prove why".

Comment: @Patrice I see your point, the second question is suspicious. I guess it didn't seem likely that they would setup a website and crowd-funding page for a homework question. Anyhow thank you greatly for your input. I guess I will have to be on more of a lookout in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the goal of Stack Exchange to have a site for **every** question in the universe (or even just the world). It's perfectly OK for a good, well researched question to be simply off topic everywhere on the current network of sites.

As such it should simply be closed.

However, if a good, on-topic somewhere, question can be teased out of the current one then it should be edited and *then* migrated to it's new home.

However, I'm not sure that the question can be edited.

Comment: What about [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @TinyGiant - it's not really a puzzle or code golf (as I understand it to be)

Comment: I don't know much about C++ but if those functions didn't produce true random numbers, and it could be worded as a challenge to produce code that did produce true random numbers , if it is actually possible to do so and it isn't a homework question, then I would think that it would be a puzzle. Am I wrong?